# unable to generate Models with Entity framework Database first using MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

[image: Entity Data Model Wizard ScreenShot]

I am creating on an `ASP.NET (C#)` Web API project and I need to include a MySQL database and `EntityFramework` using `visual studio 2019 version 16.3.3`. I have added required dll `MySQL.Data.dll`, `MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6.dll` and `Entityframework.dll` and then trying to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model under Model folder after creating model code not generated and I could not able see any changes.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors when you complete the wizard?

Comment: not getting any kind of error